# how to get my login page on node.js from localhost to a html page?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have login module which works on node.js and mongo and starts on localhost when the app.js file is initiated through command prom. I want this page to appear on the login.html file which i linked to my index.html . The login module doesn't have a html file with it.below is my app.js file.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var app = express();

app.locals.pretty = true;
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/app/public' }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/public'));



var dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost'
var dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT || 27017;
var dbName = process.env.DB_NAME || 'node-login';

 var dbURL = 'mongodb://'+dbHost+':'+dbPort+'/'+dbName;
if (app.get('env') == 'live'){
// prepend url with authentication credentials // 
   dbURL =     'mongodb://'+process.env.DB_USER+':'+process.env.DB_PASS+'@'+dbHost+':'+dbPort+'/'+dbName;
}

app.use(session({
secret: 'faeb4453e5d14fe6f6d04637f78077c76c73d1b4',
proxy: true,
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
store: new MongoStore({ url: dbURL })
})
);

require('./app/server/routes')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Post the code what you have tried? Also explain the problem statement clearly , so that others can help you easily.. Your post is too broad..

Comment: Please explain your problem properly.

Comment: Hi I have added my app.js file above. I can run the login module on localhost and it is running fine. I am not able to connect it to my login.html file in the project.

Comment: So you mean the login.html file from your static folder which is i guess inside app/public/login.html is not working?

Comment: Yes , when i open login.html it is not working.